# Where is my error for not plotting the correct data on the graph on Y coords

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

through query to database retrieve temperature values and to make sure these values are the same I want to be extracted I display them on listbox.

It is a striking thing for me that the data on the sheets is really accurate, but for example I will say that I do not have a higher temperature of 7 degrees Celsius and on the graph I see a line that passes 80 degrees Celsius.

I can not understand where my problem is in the application code

This is a meteorological application that accurately displays graphics, but the data it draws is not correct.

```
if (comboBox1.Text == temp)
{
    try
    {
        Connection.Open();
        var transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction();

        listBox3.Items.Clear();

        //SQLiteTransaction trans;
        //Connection.Open();
        //trans = Connection.BeginTransaction();
        chart1.Series["Temp"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;
        string selectTemp = "SELECT Dat,Temp FROM meteodata WHERE Station= " + comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + " AND Dat BETWEEN '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("_", "-") + "' AND '" + comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("_", "-") + "24:00" + "' ORDER by Dat";

        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(selectTemp, Connection);

        using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            transaction.Commit();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                listBox3.Show();
                label6.Show();
                chart1.Show();                

                chart1.Series["WindSpeed"].Enabled = false;
                chart1.Series["WindDirection"].Enabled = false;
                chart1.Series["Pressure"].Enabled = false;
                chart1.Series["Hum"].Enabled = false;
                chart1.Series["Rain"].Enabled = false;
                chart1.Series["RainIntensity"].Enabled = false;
                chart1.Series["SunRadiation"].Enabled = false;
                chart1.Series["Temp"].Enabled = true;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //bool iii = dr.Read();
                    {
                        chart1.Series["Temp"].Points.AddXY(dr["Dat"].ToString(), dr["Temp"].ToString());

                        listBox3.Items.Add(dr["Dat"].ToString() + " - " + dr["Temp"].ToString());
                        //MessageBox.Show("Дата"+ dr["Dat"].ToString() + "Температура: " + dr["Temp"].ToString());

                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
                Connection.Close();                    
            }
            else
            {
                dr.Close();
                Connection.Close();
            }
        }
       // Connection.Close();
    }
    catch (SQLiteException err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Caught exception: " + err.Message);
        Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

I expect my mistake to be really insignificant, because if it has to be rewritten it will have to be replaced in too many places

[image: IMAGE HERE]

Comment: sorry, but with the given information, I am not able to reproduce your problem

Comment: please try and insert the points "by hand" into the chart series. take 4 points `("27.12.2019 10:00:00", "2")` and `("27.12.2019 12:00:00", "4")` and `("27.12.2019 14:00:00", "6")` and `"27.12.2019 22:00:00", "-10"`. What do you get for a graph?

Comment: Try passing a double in as your second parameter to `.AddXY()`.

Comment: I suspect that the graph plots values like `5.4` as `54` and `5` as `5` resulting in theses downward spikes in the graph.

Comment: the problem seems to be the `,` comma. either convert it to `double` or replace the comma with a `.` dot. Your font doesn't make it easy to spot the difference between them ;) this: `c.Series[0].Points.AddXY("27.12.2019 10:00:00", "2,4");` will be plottet at 24 and this `c.Series[0].Points.AddXY("27.12.2019 10:00:00", "2.4");` at 2.4

Answer (score 0):

The `dr["Temp"].ToString()` uses the Application Culture to Converter the `double`, so an value like `5.4` is is converted in the Culture `ru-ru` to `"5,4"`.
You need to Specify the `InvariantCulture` so the values are converted to a maschine readable format, like:

```
AddXY(dr["Dat"].ToString(), dr["Temp"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: I try to add this line AddXY(dr["Dat"].ToString(), dr["Temp"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
I get this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1501 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments WindowsFormsApp1 C:\Users\admin\Desktop\MeteoAnalyzer - D.Atanasov\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\frm_main.cs 314 Active

Comment: @Pizhev of which type is `dr["Temp"]`, I assumed it is of type double